# Is there a way to enable UDP/IP header compression for PPP links/interfaces in Linux

Tags: linux, networking, ppp, pppd

How can we enable header compression for RTP/UDP packets sent over a PPP interface in linux?

Hints for any of the various header compression mechanisms (ROHC, IPHC, CRTP, etc.) are highly appreciated.

Note1: I prefer the compression to be done at the interface (not requiring the application to be modified)

Note2: I have a low BW serial link established in my linux box using pppd (named ppp0).

Note3) A similar question (with no answers) pointing out the different compression mechanisms can be found [here](http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/networking/147969-udp-ip-header-compression.html)

Comment: Not an answer, but besides van-Jacobson, [pppd](https://linux.die.net/man/8/pppd) has multiple other compression options that may or may not help. AFAIK the header compression mechanisms you mentioned are not implemented in pppd. I wouldn't know any other place to implement them except in pppd. If you really need the header compression, adding it to the pppd code should be doable.

Comment: @dirkt, thanks for your input; does any of the pppd compression options support UDP or RTP compression?

Comment: As I wrote: "AFAIK the header compression mechanisms you mentioned are not implemented in pppd". But I'd expect both `deflate` and `bsdcompress` to work on the whole packet, which includes RTP over UDP. Of course the question is if that actually saves something, so you'll have to try. There are also various link-level compression options. PPP by default also does a lot of control character escaping (it assumes they might not be properly transferred over serial), so it's worth looking into that, too.